# Potentiometer voltage change

Tags: voltage, current, measurement, resistance, potentiometer

I'm trying to understand simple things about electricity reading allaboutcircuits.com web. [This chapter](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_9/2.html) includes image which´s principle I don't understand. Here it is:
[image]

When supplying constant voltage to circuit where resistance and current change, how is it possible that change of resistance affects voltage on resistor?

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important point here is that the meter on the right side (the "level indicator") draws an insignificant amount of current. Therefore, you can assume that no current is flowing through the two-conductor cable. This means that the position of the potentiometer's wiper (the movable part) has no effect on the current drawn through any part of the potentiometer's resistance. So, the amount of current flowing through the potentiometer is constant and is determined by the total resistance of the potentiometer and the battery voltage. Although no current flows through the voltmeter it does respond to the different voltages that exist along the length of the potentiometer's resistive material.

In the real world a voltmeter will draw some current, and it's up to the user to make sure that the current drawn by the voltmeter is small compared to the currents present in the circuit being measured. When I started in this business it was common to have a voltmeter draw something like \$50\mu A\$ but good meters now are in the single microampere range. So if you really built this circuit you  might want the normal current through the potentiometer resistance to be 50x or 100x the current drawn by the meter.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't affect the voltage across the *entire* resistor. But it does affect the voltage from the *wiper position* to ground. This is no different than a voltage divider with fixed value resistors, except that the individual values are no longer fixed.